# Testing if nonlinear interactions are present

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression

An example dataset of simultaneously measured variables $X$ and $Y$ containts a few hundred datapoints. I am interested to know if the variables have a relationship that cannot fully be described by a linear relationship + i.i.d noise. One can of course plot the dataset and explore it. But in my case there are thousands of such datasets. I am interested to automatically test if such a relationship is present. I'm certain that in some datasets the variables are at least linearly related. However, if there happens to also be a nonlinear relationshi on top of that, I have no prior knowledge of the form it would take. The variables are known to have significant added noise ($SNR\approx1$). Thus, I am not interested in perfect estimation of nonlinearity. Instead, I want a measure which would tell me if a nonlinear model could extract more meaningful info from the current data than a linear model.

Here is a procedure I propose:

1. Let $y' = LinearFit(x,y)$
2. Let $\Delta y = y -y'$
3. Estimate Mutual Information $MI = I(x:\Delta y)$
4. Test if $MI>0$, for example using a permutation test

The idea is the following. If the data has only a linear relationship, then, after subtracting this relationship, the probability distribution of the residual would be separable $P[x, \Delta y] = P[x]P[\Delta y]$, and thus the mutual information would be zero.

**Questions**:

- Is this a reasonable approach?
- Has it been tried before? Does it work in practice?
- Are there other, perhaps more established, tests of non-linearity?

Comment: "Tests of non-linearity" include many popular *goodness of fit* tests. The idea is to add more explanatory variables in the regression, variables that are nonlinear functions of the original ones, to see whether that improves the fit: when it does, you reject a null hypothesis of a linear relation. In this way you use standard modeling and testing machinery; there's no need to invent new procedures. These tests vary according to the class of nonlinear functions you choose: that's a matter we can't help you with based on your abstract description of the data and the model(s) you are employing.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your reply. I'll clarify. My original question is: are there non-parametric tests of non-linear relation between two variables? Is this a bad question? If I understand you correctly, I should take a few datasets, fit a bunch of nonlinear functions, see which ones fit better, then fit those to the rest of datasets. Ok, what if I look at first 10 datasets and find they are all more or less linear. Should I conclude that the rest of the datasets are linear? I cannot exclude that they have nonlinearities from different families. Do I have to explore every dataset individually?

Comment: It all depends on how similar the datasets might be.  You don't have to explore every one individually.  Moreover, if you use nonparametric models you will have nonparametric tests.  Consider adding some simple splines to the basic models, for instance.  The subject matter might suggest good appropriate alternative models, too.  But your program sounds like a good idea: explore a handful of datasets in detail to verify your assumptions and expectations and to test out whatever approach you adopt.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I'll do that and see how far I get. You see, as a theoretical physicist working in data-based neuroscience, it is very hard to settle for heuristic approaches. I have been drilled to look for abstract omnipotent solutions. That's why I am so much in love with non-parametric approaches. But over the last few years, especially due to this forum, I am starting to learn that there is nothing perfect in statistics and that I have to find the right tool for the job every time